# Class method works on lists once, then throws up an attribute error in the second turn

Tags: python, attributeerror

I created a method in a class. When I call the method the first time, it seems to work and provides the required output. When I run it again, I get an "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'trek'". Here is the code:

```
#this creates a playing card with a suit and value
class Kaart:
    def __init__(self, kleur, waarde):
        self.kleur = kleur
        self.waarde = waarde
        self.value = waarde
        if waarde == "Boer":
            self.value = 11
        if waarde == "Vrouw":
            self.value = 12
        if waarde == "Heer":
            self.value = 13
        if waarde == "Aas":
            self.value = 14
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.kleur, self.waarde
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.kleur} {self.waarde}"
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other.value
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.value > other.value
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.value < other.value

k1 = Kaart("Ruiten", 2)
k2 = Kaart("Harten", "Heer")
k3 = Kaart("Klaveren", 7)

k4 = Kaart("Harten", 4)
k5 = Kaart("Harten", 3)
k6 = Kaart("Schoppen", 8)
```

```
#This creates a couple of stacks of three cards.
class Trekstapel:
    def __init__(self, kaarten):
        self.stack = kaarten
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.stack
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.stack)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.stack)
    def __getitem__(self, n):
        return self.stack[n]
    def __add__(self, other):
        return list(self.stack) + list(other)
    def __radd__ (self, other):
        return list(other) + list(self.stack)
    def voegtoe(self, kaart):
        self.stack.insert(0, kaart)
        return self.stack
    def trek(self):
        tempList = self.stack
        card = tempList[-1]
        self.stack.pop()
        return card
    

t1 = Trekstapel([k1, k2, k3])
t2 = Trekstapel([k4, k5, k6])
```

```
#This is the "game" whereby each player compares a card and the player with the higher card gets to keep both cards.
class Oorlogje:
    def __init__(self, player_1, player_2):
        self.deck = player_1
        self.opponent = player_2
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.deck} vs {self.opponent}"
    def turn(self):
        hand_1 = self.deck.trek()
        hand_2 = self.opponent.trek()
        if hand_1 > hand_2: 
            newList = [hand_2, hand_1]
            self.deck = newList + self.deck 
        if hand_1 < hand_2:
            newList = [hand_1, hand_2]
            self.opponent = newList + self.opponent
        return f"{self.deck} vs {self.opponent}"
    def win(self):
        if len(self.deck) == 0:            
            print("Player 2 won!")
            return True
        if len(self.opponent) == 0:            
            print("Player 1 won!")
            return True
        return False


game = Oorlogje(t1, t2)
loop = 0

print(game)

while game.win() == False:
    print(game.turn())
    loop += 1

print("Game ended in", loop, "turns.")
```

Finally, the output I get:

```
[Ruiten 2, Harten Heer, Klaveren 7] vs [Harten 4, Harten 3, Schoppen 8]
[Ruiten 2, Harten Heer] vs [Klaveren 7, Schoppen 8, Harten 4, Harten 3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Bestanden/Cursussen/corepy/speelkaarten.py", line 141, in <module>
    print(game.turn())
  File "D:/Bestanden/Cursussen/corepy/speelkaarten.py", line 117, in turn
    hand_2 = self.opponent.trek()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'trek'
```

Please note the method causing the issue described is in the stack class.

I've been playing around with it and changing the code to what you see now, but I'm honestly not quite sure what to do. I know my hand is a list, it's supposed to be. It doesn't seem like the type has changed and the method worked on it the list type before.

Maybe a pair of fresh eyes will help.

Comment: Well, if `self.opponent` is supposed to be of the type `Trekstapel`, why are you setting it to `self.opponent = newList + self.opponent`? You're replacing it with a list. And obviously a `list` is not the same thing as a `Trekstapel`. Why are you replacing it with a `list` and then expecting it to still have properties that a `Trekstapel` has?

Comment: Ah. I didn't realise that would change it. Thank you very much for pointing that out to me. It seems to work now!

Comment: As an alternative to modifying `Oorlogje`, you could try changing `__add__` and `__radd__` in the `Trekstapel` class so that they return new instances of `Trekstapel`.

Comment: That sounds like a better solution than mine. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

```py
newList = [hand_1, hand_2]
self.opponent = newList + self.opponent
```

is causing the error you're seeing down the line

`self.opponent` is no longer a `Trekstapel` since it got reassigned to a `list`.

So later when:

```py
hand_2 = self.opponent.trek()
```

Python tells you:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'trek'
```

That the `list` does not have a `trek` attribute.

Comment: Thank you! I have changed it to self.opponent = Trekstapel(newList + self.opponent) and it all seems to work now.